# Creating a shell script version of terminal commands

Tags: shell-script

I am just starting to learn the basics of Linux terminal and I'm a little confused on converting terminal commands into shell script. How would I approach creating a script file in the Linux terminal and creating a shell script version of my code below:

```
curl -O https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/cities.csv
head -n 12 cities.csv
```

Comment: Is the URL predetermined or you need to pass it to the script?

Comment: I need to pass it to the script

Comment: Put `#!/bin/sh` atop the file, and apply `chmod +x file.sh` to make it executable.Call it like `~$ ./file.sh`.

Comment: If you are interested in learning more, consider [GreyCat&Lhunath's Bash Guide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide).

Answer (score 7):

#### Using a text editor to create your script

Scripts are saved to text files. You can create one in a text editor, like `gedit` or `nano`:

```
$ nano yourscript.sh
```

The filename in general and the [filename extension in particular does not matter](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31760/423679). In your script file, you have to [declare the executable of the interpreter to run it (a shebang)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29). Then add your code. To save your script in `nano`, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then type `y` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

#### Composing your script

If you pass arguments to the script, you can reference them in your code by number (the first passed argument is `$1`, the second one is `$2`, and so on). `$0` is the script's name itself.

As a general rule, [always use double quotes around variables](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/423679).

Taking your code, for example, the script might be:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
curl -O "$1"
head -n 12 cities.csv
```

[There can be a space after `#!`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/276751/423679), but it is not necessary. In most cases, you can check `$0` variable in terminal for the [shell executable interpreting your commands in terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/9501/423679):

```
$ type $0
bash is /usr/bin/bash
```

#### Improving your code

Assuming that all you want are the first 12 lines of the downloaded file, you can [skip saving the downloaded file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/429818/423679) to disk and [pipe it to the next command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/423679):

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
curl -s "$1" | head -n 12
```

As a bonus, it allows you to omit the filename in your script.

#### Running the script

Assuming you save your script as `yourscript.sh`, add permission to execute it first:

```
$ chmod +x yourscript.sh
```

Then, to run it, you need to specify the path to it and provide the arguments. If it is in the current directory, you can specify the path to it by prepending `./` like:

```
$ ./yourscript.sh 'https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/data/csv/cities.csv'
```

Comment: Do I put the '#!/bin/bash' code first or the code to make it executable first? Also how do I create the file in the first place bc when I enter 'chmod +x yourscript.sh' or './yourscript.sh', I get the message "cannot access ‘scriptex.sh’: No such file or directory"

Comment: Make sure you use quotes for all variables containing user input (security!): `curl -O "$1"`

Comment: @user10649856, this is old comment but for future users wondering about this. Regarding the first question "to put `#!/bin/bash` code first or to make file executable at the first place" -> it is irrelevant which order you will use. Regarding the second question "how to create a file" -> a lot of ways: `touch some_file`, `echo >some_file`, `>some_file`, `vi some_file`, ...

Answer (score 3):

All the command you type one by one at the prompt, can simply be put in a script file and executed once.

1. The only requirement is the interpreter line, which should be at the start of file

   ```
     #!/bin/sh
   ```

   you can write script for other like bash (`#!/bin/bash`) or zsh (`#!/bin/zsh`)
2. Make you script executable by running `chmod +x scriptFile.sh` (sh extension is good to have, as it indicates that it's a script file)
3. Run the script by

   ./scriptFile.sh

Optional: You can add the directory path to PATH variable, to be able to execute the script from any directory by just calling `scriptFile.sh` just like you invoke any other shell command `ls`, or `cat`

Comment: One more question, which command saves the script file?

Comment: @user10649856 you need to write the script file via normal text editor whichever you are comfortable with.