# Shell script to use mount?

Tags: shell-script

I am mounting a directory /dev/xyz to folder /abc using command

```
   mount --bind /dev/xyz 
   /abc
```

How could I use this command using shell script?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. What is preventing you from placing this in a script?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating a shell script version of terminal commands](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611694/creating-a-shell-script-version-of-terminal-commands)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost the same way. Just create a bash script:

```
vi mount.sh
```

Insert or i is responsible for inserting. Right button of the mouse for pasting. Esc for exiting the insert mode, Then all you have to do after Esc is to type :x to save and exit the bash script file edition mode.

Add a shebang [check what shebang is at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20a%20shebang%20is,bang%2C%20or%20hash%2Dpling.)

Add a command to the file below the shebang.

```
mount --bind /dev/xyz /abc
```

Make bash script executable using

```
chmod +x mount.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "mount --bind /dev/xyz /abc" >mount.sh && chmod 755 mount.sh && ./mount.sh
```

Comment: Nice one-liner. :)