# how to run several files in linux

Tags: bash, shell-script

I have a very basic question. I want to run several files in my linux. Name of the files is `input1.i`, `input2.i` and so on. After running each input file, I should have an output for each of them. I tried the following method but it failed:

```
for file in input*
do
mpiexec -n 6 ./tiger-opt -i file.i # this line runs my inputs
done
```

the error is

```
Failed to get real path for file.i
```

I very much appreciate if anyone can help me.

Comment: The `-i file.i` is taken verbatim. You need to expand your iteration variable like:  `mpiexec ..... -i "$file"`  You don't need to add the `.i` there since it is already taken from `input`

Comment: Dear @ValentinBajrami, your hint solved my problem. I did it with `mpiexec -n 6 ./tiger-opt -i "$file"`. Do you know how I can make a bash file instead of a for loop?

Comment: See here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/611694/creating-a-shell-script-version-of-terminal-commands